# The difference between lists and sequences

Tags: c#, f#, list, sequences

I'm trying to understand the difference between sequences and lists.

In F# there is a clear distinction between the two. However in C# I have seen programmers refer to IEnumerable collections as a sequence. Is what makes IEnumerable a sequence the fact that it returns an object to iterate through the collection?

Perhaps the real distinction is purely found in functional languages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really - you tend to have random access to a list, as well as being able to get its count quickly etc. Admittedly linked lists don't have the random access nature... but then they don't implement `IList<T>`. There's a grey area between the facilities provided by a particular platform and the general concepts.

Sequences (as represented by `IEnumerable<T>`) are read-only, forward-only, one item at a time, and potentially infinite. Of course any one *implementation* of a sequence may also be a list (e.g. `List<T>`) but when you're treating it as a sequence, you can basically iterate over it (repeatedly) and that's it.

Comment: +1 Good explanation - it is a bit of a fuzzy distinction but an important one to understand.

Comment: how can a forward-only can be "basically iterate over it **(repeatedly)**"?

Comment: @Jeb50: Because each time you call `GetEnumerator()`, it returns a new iterator. It would be feasible for an implementation to only allow that to be called once, but *most* implementations allow for repeated iteration.

Comment: so like each time it's cloned to understand the "repeatedly"?

Comment: @Jeb50: That depends on what you mean by "cloned" and what the implementation does. For example, the `List<T>` implementation just creates a new "cursor" over the list each time you call `GetEnumerator()`. No cloning. Another implementation could give you a random (potentially infinite) sequence each time you call `GetEnumerator()`, with no cloning. Another implementation (e.g. for ConcurrentDictionary) *could* take a snapshot each time you call `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: When I said "cloned" it's a generic non-tech mean, not the `.clone()`. But I now got it, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the confusion may arise from the fact that collections like `List<T>` implement the interface `IEnumerable<T>`. If you have a subtype relationship in general (e.g. supertype `Shape` with two subtypes `Rectangle` and `Circle`), you can interpret the relation as an "is-a" hierarchy.

This means that it is perfectly fine to say that "`Circle` *is a* `Shape`" and similarly, people would say that "`List<T>` *is an* `IEnumerable<T>`" that is, "list *is a* sequence". This makes some sense, because a list is a special type of a sequence. In general, sequences can be also lazily generated and infinite (and these types cannot also be lists). An example of a (perfectly valid) sequence that cannot be generated by a list would look like this:

```
// C# version                           // F# version
IEnumerable<int> Numbers() {            let rec loop n = seq {
  int i = 0;                               yield n
  while (true) yield return i++;           yield! loop(n + 1) }
}                                       let numbers = loop(0)
```

This would be also true for F#, because F# `list` type also implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but functional programming doesn't put that strong emphasis on object oriented point of view (and implicit conversions that enable the "is a" interpretation are used less frequently in F#).

Answer (score 2):

Sequence content is calculated on demand so you can implement for example infinite sequence without affecting your memory.
So in C# you can write a sequence, for example

```
IEnumerable<int> Null() {
  yield return 0;
}
```

It will return infinite sequence of zeros.
You can write

```
int[] array = Null().Take(10).ToArray()
```

And it will take 10*4 bytes of memory despite sequence is infinite.
So as you see, C# does have distinction between sequence and collection